# Unable to copy array using setstate hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am fetching data from backend using axios whenever I am trying to update hooks it is not updating.
The data is JSON from where I am extracting data and trying to set element. It might sound silly but can somebody tell me what is dependent array?

I keep getting this
**Line 18:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'elements'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps**

Here is code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const res = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('/data');
      const data = result.data;
      console.log(data);
      setElements(elements => [...elements, data]);
      console.log(elements);
    };
    res();
  }, []);
 console.log(elements.map(element => console.log(element)));
  return <div className='App'>Hello</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Normally when you set state after async function finishes you have to [check if the component is mounted before you set the state](https://github.com/jmlweb/isMounted)

Comment: thanks for the tip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `console.log` outside your `effect`. You're already using the `updater` version of `useState`

```
 setElements(elements => [...elements, data])
```

The missing dependecy warning is coming from `console.log(elements)`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const res = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('/data');
      const data = result.data;
      console.log(data);
      setElements(elements => [...elements, data]);
    };
    res();
  }, []);

  console.log(elements);

  return <div className='App'>Hello</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Also when I am trying to display my data which I am getting from mongo db I am not being able to get it. I did  console.log(elements.map(element => console.log(element))); outside useEffect which gives undefined why?

Comment: where are you trying to log your data? Could you update the question (or post another one) with this problem?

Comment: outside useEffect basically I want every data to be displayed on page but I keep failing

Comment: Update the question with the code or share a sandbox and I'll take a look. I'm sure that's a small problem

Comment: I will post as a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58191050/unable-to-access-data-which-is-copied-using-usestate-hook

Answer (score 1):

`Missing dependency` warning is because you use `console.log(elements)` inside the useEffect.
And your elements log is not showing latest result because state is not changed (yet)

Just add a `useEffect` to keep track of elements changes like below.

```
 function App() {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const res = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('/data');
      const data = result.data;
      console.log(data);
      setElements(elements => [...elements, data]);
    };
    res();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => console.log(elements), [elements])

  return <div className='App'>Hello</div>;
}

export default App;
```

To answer your question;

The dependency array is their to let React know when the useEffect in this case should be triggered. So the useEffect i added, only triggers when its dependency `elements` is changed.

Comment: Offcourse it is, it totally makes sense. The second hook should be triggered when elements changes, the first hook we want to take rest here ;)

Sure, the second one is now only for demo purpose to log the updated elements but still. Its the same as having multiple useState's of similar.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are puting the array data inside elements, `setElements(elements => [...elements, data]);` so it will be array inside array.
Try the below :

```
function App() {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const res = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('/data');
      const data = result.data;
      console.log(data);
      setElements([...elements, data]);
    };
    res();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => console.log(elements), [elements])

  return <div className='App'>Hello</div>;
}

export default App;
```