# Unable to access data which is copied using useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to get the data copied set to elemnents what am I doing wrong here? I am a newbie in react. Here is a [json](https://github.com/iamdudeman/Periodic-Table-Database/blob/master/Periodic%20Elements.json)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const res = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('/data');
      const data = result.data;
      setElements(elements => [...elements, data]);
    };
    res();
  }, []);
  console.log(elements.map(element => console.log(element)));
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      Hello
      {elements.map(element => (
        <div key={element._id}>{element.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you spread the `data` array in the `setElements` call ?

Comment: what's in `result.data` ? `object` or `array` of objects ?

Comment: I have shared the result to myjson click on it the elements are the data which I am getting from backend

Comment: Please, include the relevant snippet of JSON inside the question description itself. Any off-site resource should only be used as a reference and shouldn't be needed to answer the question.

Comment: will keep in mind

Comment: Please _edit this question_ to include the JSON, not "keep in mind" for later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding the elements to the array but the whole dataset. Just spread the data elements into your "new" elements and you are good to go.

You want to change this

```
setElements(elements => [...elements, data]);
```

to this

```
setElements(elements => [...elements, ...data.elements]);
```

So end result would be

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const res = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('/data');
      const data = result.data;
      setElements(elements => [...elements, ...data.elements]);
    };
    res();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      Hello
      {elements.map(element => (
        <div key={element._id}>{element.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And just a small thing `element._id` doesn't exist in your data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `data.elements` (which is an `array`) it's not beeing correctly merged.Use `spread`

```
setElements(elements => [...elements, ...data.elements])
```

Or `concat`

```
setElements(elements => elements.concat(data.elements))
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `flat` here, `elements.concat(data.elements)` will work just fine. `flat` will have no effect on the code as listed. I would be wary of recommending the use of `flat` given how new it is.

Comment: Thanks for the warning